# extending an invitation with alot of information in it

Tags: sentence

EDIT: The invitation is being extending to someone called N that A/B has just met the invitation is being extended by A to N as B is already going.

デニスレストランにいきませんか。Would you like to goto Denny’s restaurant (after class?) *invitation*
Would like to change to. “my friend works at Denny’s restaurant. We are going there after class would you like to come?

can anyone help me with this sentence i realize i am obviously missing クラス and some effective way of putting it into the sentence as well as ともだち。 but i am having trouble making such a big sentence. am fairly new to Japanese language like lesson 6 of genki up to te form if that makes any sense to anyone.

perhaps it would be better to say "our friend works at dennys." we are going there after class. would you like to come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Japanese, pronouns like I/we/they/you and so on are rarely spoken. Instead they depend on context and verb conjugation to convey who it is they are talking about. So I wouldn't worry very much about whether to say "my" vs. "our".

I think the simplest version of what you're trying to say would be:

友達{ともだち}がデニーズレストランでアルバイトしてる。クラスのあと、みんなと一緒{いっしょ}に行{い}きませんか？

Choosing this phrasing, I'm assuming the person you're speaking to already knows or is standing with you and all the people who are part of "minna". If they do not know your group of friends who are going, then instead of みんな, you could use ぼくら/ぼくたち/私{わたし}たち　と一緒｛いっしょ｝　instead, which indicates you and some other people, possibly including some unknown people.